# Retrieving deployment date and campaign owner of ExactTarget Campaign

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud

In Marketing Cloud, when you create a campaign, you have the option to set a deployment date and campaign owner as per the screenshot below.

I am trying to find what method I can use to retrieve the values for 'deployment date' and 'campaign owner' as the REST API method to [Retrieve Single Campaign](https://code.exacttarget.com/api/campaigns-retrieve-single-campaign) does not provide this in the response. Please can someone advise?

[image: edit campaign interface]

Comment: Odd for sure. We are asking the product team for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with the "powers that be" yesterday, and here is what they told me (direct quote):

Currently, there isn’t a way to retrieve that information via Fuel. However, when 2014-04 is released to production (end of May), the following Fuel route will return deployment date and campaign owner:

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub-internal/v1/campaigns/{id}

Note that this is an “internal” route. That is, it isn’t officially documented, and it’s also subject to change. However, at least for the near term, that route will return the information that the customer needs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, we've tried this method (as it's now June) and get the error `{documentation: https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/403 errorcode: 0 message: "Not Authorized" }`. We're using the token generated from https://auth-test.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken (as we're working on sandbox). Please can you advise why this is not working? Other requests are working, but not to this hub-internal endpoint. Perhaps it does not support sandbox tokens?

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I have tried a production account and use the GET request `https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub-internal/v1/campaigns/419?access_token=k9fyngny47wdcnpy3k8skh7x` — will this still be implemented?